# How to do this simple MySQL statement without resorting to a sub query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Users table:

```
user_id | avatar
----------------------------------
1       | file-name.jpg
2       | friendly-ghost.jpg
```

Profile views table:

```
profile_user_id | viewer_user_id
--------------------------------
2               | 1
```

I need to get all the information about the user who user 1 viewed.

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `profile_views`
INNER JOIN `users` ON profile_views.viewer_user_id = users.user_id
WHERE profile_views.viewer_user_id = '1'
```

This gives back:

```
profile_user_id: 2
avatar: file-name.jpg
```

As you can see it's giving back user 1's avatar not user 2's. I need it to give back the avatar of the user that user 1 viewed. In this case that would be "friendly-ghost.jpg".

Is there a way to do this without resorting to a sub query?

Comment: is saying that the avatar shown in his query result belongs to user 1; it should be that of user 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, avatar
FROM profile_views AS PV
     INNER JOIN users AS U ON U.user_id = PV.profile_user_id
WHERE PV.viewer_user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users
JOIN profile_views ON (profile_user_id = user_id AND viewer_user_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your join condition will work.

`ON profile_views.profile_user_id = users.user_id`